# when I use an if statement to move the cursor using a flex sensor then after bending the sensor longer time the values remain the same

Tags: python, arduino, sensors

when I bend the flex sensor for a short period of time it works well but after bending the sensor for a longer period of time then letting it go does not change the value of the flex sensor printing to my computer and my cursor keeps moving.

```
import serial
import time
import pyautogui
from stopwatch import Stopwatch
ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)


data =[]                       # empty list to store the data
for i in range(500000):

    b = ser.readline()         # read a byte string
    string_n = b.decode()     # decode byte string into Unicode
    string = string_n.rstrip() # remove \n and \r
flt = int(string)
val = flt# convert string to float
print(flt)
data.append(flt)




if flt==197 :
    pyautogui.move(10, 0, 0)
```

I want the cursor to move 5 steps ahead if the value of the flex sensor is 197 , when using the above code this works well only for short periods when bending my sensor but after long periods of time say 5 seconds after bending the sensor, the flex sensor value remains 197 and does not change and the cursor keeps moving.

Comment: Do not spam the tags. Why C tag?

Comment: the arduino code is in C, I am using python to read from the serial port

Comment: i thought including th arduino code would not be relevant to this question

Comment: Before setting your cursor to make sure that receive data is ok, add a print statement in the loop and check that. I think your problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

You run a for loop, instead of that  run a while loop and it's will be fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is very hard to understand your answer. Please modify your answer and provide sample source code to solve the problem.